# apache2: /etc/apache2/sites-available is missing on macos

Tags: django, apache

I am trying to configure apache2 so that it communicates with django and I am unable to the 'sites-available' directory where I believe a 'defaults' directory should reside.
The following is my file structure under the 'etc/apache2/' directory:

```
├── extra
│   ├── httpd-autoindex.conf
│   ├── httpd-dav.conf
│   ├── httpd-default.conf
│   ├── httpd-info.conf
│   ├── httpd-languages.conf
│   ├── httpd-manual.conf
│   ├── httpd-mpm.conf
│   ├── httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf
│   ├── httpd-ssl.conf
│   ├── httpd-userdir.conf
│   ├── httpd-vhosts.conf
│   └── proxy-html.conf
├── httpd.conf
├── httpd.conf.bak
├── httpd.conf.pre-update
├── magic
├── mime.types
├── original
│   ├── extra
│   │   ├── httpd-autoindex.conf
│   │   ├── httpd-dav.conf
│   │   ├── httpd-default.conf
│   │   ├── httpd-info.conf
│   │   ├── httpd-languages.conf
│   │   ├── httpd-manual.conf
│   │   ├── httpd-mpm.conf
│   │   ├── httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf
│   │   ├── httpd-ssl.conf
│   │   ├── httpd-userdir.conf
│   │   ├── httpd-vhosts.conf
│   │   └── proxy-html.conf
│   └── httpd.conf
├── other
│   └── php5.conf
└── users
    ├── Guest.conf
    ├── aphexlog.conf
    └── secops.conf
```

If anyone knows if there is a possibility of a alternative config file with the same properties or some other solution... maybe I am just being dumb but everything that I have found online indicates that I should have this properties file.

Any and all help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sites-available` is a concept from Debian-derived distributions of Linux. MacOS does not have it, and neither do most other Linux flavours.

Instead you need to put your configuration directly in httpd.conf.

(Note, it's unusual to run a production system on a Mac; if you're just doing this for development, you can use the built-in runserver rather than messing around with Apache.)

Comment: Thank you, this help a lot. I am of coarse not planning on running prod on my mac lol but testing some things out and hopefully porting it over to a ubuntu server for further testing once i get thing working on my machine.

Comment: what is the `the built-in runserver` you are referring to ?